# $write_result->errors throws "Undefined Property" when there are no errors

Tags: php, soap-client, bronto

Using pre-written code from Bronto,  it builds a soap client,  calls a function on it,  then parses the results.  The parsing code looks like this:

```
if ($write_result->errors) {
    print "There was a problem adding or updating the contact:\n";
    print_r($write_result->results);
    exit;
 } elseif ($write_result->results[0]->isNew == true) {
    print "The contact has been added.  Id: " . $write_result->results[0]->id . "\n";
 } else {
    print "The contact's information has been updated.  Id: " . $write_result->results[0]->id . "\n";
 }
```

Whenever there ARE errors, they get caught and printed by the first if statement.  But when there AREN'T errors,  the console gets an "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$errors" message printed out.      Is this right?  Is there a way to turn off the notice?   It doesn't cause any problems,  but I can see how it would confuse a non-techy reading the output logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check first if the [property exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php):

```
if (property_exists($write_result, 'errors'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the property exists instead of accessing it directly:

```
if (isset($write_result->errors))
```

Or to check if it exists *and* not empty at once (just to be sure in case the API changes and provides an actual empty array or empty string if no errors occured):

```
if (!empty($write_result->errors))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the property exists first:

```
if (property_exists($write_result, 'errors') && $write_result->errors)
{
  // ...
}
```

See: [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php).